# How to use MYSQL to track user likes

Tags: mysql

For websites like Digg.  How can you use MYSQL to track when someone likes an article?

It seems simple enough to just keep track of the total number of likes.  The part I don't understand, is how to 
1. keep users from only voting on something once and 
2. allow users to click on their profile to see the stories they have liked.

Would you have a column in the table containing the story info that you just add comma separated user names?  You could keep track of who has liked a story, but the data would get huge, especially for websites like digg that has 100,000 users or more.  And how would you allow the user to see all the stories they have liked?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You would need a row for each like. Don't use comma-separated lists.

---

> how to 1. keep users from only voting on something once

Create a unique index on articleid, userid.

---

> And how would you allow the user to see all the stories they have liked?

```
SELECT articleid FROM likes WHERE userid = 42
```

---

> but the data would get huge

Yes, it could get huge. Most websites will easily be able to cope with just a single database. Very large websites will need to use a cluster to store data on several machines. The data needs to be partitioned so that the application knows on which server to find the data.

Answer (score 0):

In Social Network these days are like the Graph dataStructure.
Where every entity like people,photo,video,status-updates, comments etc are nodes of the graph and likes,unlikes are connections between two nodes.

ideally you would have a Table for Likes where you would just add a like.
where you would store who liked, what is liked in columns and other info.

Complex social networks do more than just this.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the likes in a seperate table called story_likes with two columns : story_id and user_id.

1) Put a constraint in the database that the combination of these should be unique. That way your user can like a story only once.
2) You can pull the stories that the user likes from this table and pull other story details using the story id you have. 100,000 rows is not that big for a MYSQL database.

You can also allow your users to dislike a story by having a column for state=ENUM('LIKED', 'DISLIKED').